# Feature to find out keywords used in Wordpress blogs

Tags: search, wordpress, blogging

In wordpress blog, are there any feature or tool available to find out which are the keywords used to search in blogs?

E.g. If anyone has used words like sam, flowers, college etc in blogs I have created, how do I know these keywords are used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are plugins like [Search Meter](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-meter/) which will automatically record what people type into your search box.

[image]